# Java regex to find double quote

Tags: java, regex

What is the regular expression to find double quotes at the beginning of a string in Java?

For example, I have this code:

```
if (allLexeme[allLexemeIter].matches("\""))
```

and that works for the string `" this`
because there is a space after the double quotes,
but does not work for the string `"this`

Comment: `matches()` tries to match the entire input against the pattern, so it shouldn't work for either case.  If you want to use `matches()`, the pattern would be `\".*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( someString.startsWith("\"") )
```

Answer (score 3):

The `match()` method requires that the entire input string be matched by the regular expression. So the regular expression `"\""` can only match the character sequence `"`

You can use the [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method, which will find the "next" occurrence of the regular expression (a `Matcher` is stateful, tracking its progress through the input).

Or, you can alter the regular expression to match the entire input and keep using the `match()` method. Something like this: `"\".*"`. But that probably isn't what you want. It depends on what you plan to do with the matched group.